# Using pandas, how can I group/aggregate summing cases where boolean columns are true?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame constructed from a database query.  Each row in the frame has a database id, date, job, an issues boolean, and a fixed boolean.  For example:

```
data = [
    {'id': 1, 'date': '2020-02-01', 'job': 'ABC', 'issue': True, 'fixed': False},
    {'id': 2, 'date': '2020-02-01', 'job': 'ABC', 'issue': False, 'fixed': False},
    {'id': 3, 'date': '2020-02-01', 'job': 'ABC', 'issue': True, 'fixed': True},
    {'id': 4, 'date': '2020-02-01', 'job': 'DEF', 'issue': True, 'fixed': True}
]
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to do a `groupby` and `agg` where I am grouping by job and date, and getting the count of 'issues' and 'fixed' that are True.  Something like:

```
result_data = [
    {'date': '2020-02-01', 'job': 'ABC', 'issue': 2, 'fixed': 1},
    {'date': '2020-02-01', 'job': 'DEF', 'issue': 1, 'fixed': 1}
]
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_data)
```

The code would look something like:

```
result_df = data_df.groupby(['date', 'job']).agg({'issue': 'sum-true', 'fixed': 'sum-true'})
```

but I am not sure what `'sum-true'` should be.  Not, I cant just filter the whole DF by the column being true, and summing, as `issue` might be `True`, while `fixed` is `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```py
>>> df.groupby(['date', 'job'])[['issue', 'fixed']].sum()
                issue  fixed
date       job              
2020-02-01 ABC    2.0    1.0
           DEF    1.0    1.0
```

Simply summing a boolean vector will return `True` counts.

And if you want the data in the exact format you specified above, just `reset_index`:

```py
>>> df.groupby(['date', 'job'])[['issue', 'fixed']].sum().reset_index()
         date  job  issue  fixed
0  2020-02-01  ABC    2.0    1.0
1  2020-02-01  DEF    1.0    1.0
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed to work in all cases?  I could have sworn I tried this exact code earlier, and it was returning either 1.0 (if there were 1 or more) or 0.0 (if there were no True values).  Of course running the code you posted worked perfectly..  I'll need to figure out what I was doing differently before.

Comment: @MarkD, the situation you describe seems like you may have been using `.max()` for aggregation (I doubt that was actually the case, however). Perhaps it's an issue with the types of the `issue` and `fixed` fields, coming from that database query? I don't know, maybe the field were stored as strings in the database for some reason and didn't convert to boolean in pandas.

Comment: Hard to know without a more complete representative dataset, unfortunately.

Comment: would explcitally calling `agg` (as in my example above) change anything?  I just realized I also need to count the total number of entries for each.  So something like: `.agg({'issue': ['sum', 'count'], 'fixed': ['sum']})`   Ultimately I am trying to get (from a large database table) the number of issues, and number of fixed issues for each job/date .  (Note- the agg call I just posted seems to be working great.  I was just concerned as it didn't seem to work a few minutes ago)